# Блок выходит за границы экрана при уменьшении экрана (overflow не помогает)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[github pages](https://roderen.github.io/agro/)

[репозиторий](https://github.com/Roderen/agro)

При уменьшении экрана блок .gallery выходит за границы экрана. Overflow для html и body не помогает (может не туда писал, но обычно помогал)

Другими словами - появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите?

Comment: @DiD Нужно, чтобы не появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки при уменьшении экрана. То есть, чтобы до экрана в ширину 500px этот блок (.gallery) уменьшался. Я пробовал добавлять для .gallery, .container_gallery и для .group_img a - width: с разными процентами; Возможно получится для самих имг задавать разный width при определённой ширине, но придётся очень много писать top и left для .group_img a.

Comment: Кстати говоря, на body `overflow: hidden` у вас как ра и не прописан, зато прописан на html (что бесполезно, так как за границу тега html может попасть только сам body)

Comment: попробуйте предложенный мной скрипт. Прямо ничего не меняя копируя-вставляя. Вы можете вставить этот код без `<script></script>` в консоли браузера без непосредственных изменений на сайте. Отпишите по результатам.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить где-нибудь в код:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('resize',(e)=> { 
  document.querySelector('.container_gallery').style.transform = 
    document.body.clientWidth>1300 ? '' : 
      `scale(${document.body.clientWidth/1380}) translate(${-(1300-document.body.clientWidth)/2}px)`; 
});
</script>
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: да, скрол не появляется, но блок уходит за пределы страницы, а нужно, чтобы блок даже при 768пх был такой же как и при 1366пх то есть умещался весь в экран.

Comment: Так это надо было написать в вопросе. У вас галерея с абсолютным позиционированием. Ей надо пересчитывать позиционирование с каждым ресайзом. Либо масштабировать трансформацией браузера, что не очень комильфо делать с фотографиями.

Comment: А ты делал когда-то подобное как у меня? Если да, то сложно ли было/муторно?

Comment: я поменял код в ответе, но в этом коде цифры подобраны вручную. Если вы что-то поменяете, их придется заново подбирать.

Answer (score 0):

прямо в блок gallery (или его класс) впишите overflow-x: scroll, пример:

```
 <div class="gallery" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
  ...
 </div>
```

или

```
 <style>
 .gallery { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    ...
 }
 </style>
 <div class="gallery">
  ...
 </div>
```

тогда Ваши фотки станут просматриваемыми на мобильной версии, ну или сюда впишите overflow:hidden, если надо скрыть.
также поменяйте на display: inline в блок icons

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне не нужен горизонтальный скрол. Мне нужно, чтобы весь блок gallery умещался в экран (до 500пх) и без какого либо скрола.

Comment: Вам надо его растянуть/сжать или обрезать?

Comment: сжать и именно сам блок, а не имгшки по отдельности.К примеру экран 768пх и этот блок должен быть таким как и при экране 1366пх

Comment: у Вас все фотки в абсолютных величинах стоят

Comment: замените на position:relative, тогда получите то, что хотите

Comment: Да это понятно, что с абсолютным не выйдет. Получается единственный вариант (в моём случае) - это при каждом уменьшении экрана переставлять сами фотки (top, left)?

Comment: А вы делали когда-то что-то подобное как тут и часто ли приходилось делать?

Comment: ну не конкретно подобное, похожее по смыслу да, и часто. замените left/top пиксели на вычисляемые величины (%, rem, vw/vh) и добавьте relative